# ¿Qué significa "púlveo"?

Tags: significado, adjetivos, palabras-raras

En el microrrelato *Botellas* de Graciela Tomassini aparece la siguiente oración:

> Vaciadas de los licores que alguna vez contuvieron, las variopintas redomas conservan un sedimento **púlveo** o viscoso de vino, sangre, tósigo, agua tofana, cuya prolongada ausencia no evita que las huellas tiñan levemente los fondos, como una resaca que no termina de despedirse.

La palabra "púlveo" no figura en el diccionario de la Real Academia Española, y en Google aparecen muy pocos resultados con esta palabra. Por eso no me queda claro qué significa.

Comment: yo intentaria buscar mas lo que el escritor trato de decir, 
tambien trate de buscar la palabra, pero no me queda mas que inferior que es una invencion del escritor para definer "polvoso"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dado el contexto, yo entiendo que quiere decir que ese líquido contiene polvo u otras partículas similares.

Es cierto que en español lo más común habría sido usar `polvoriento` para indicar "lleno de polvo"

> [polvoriento, ta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TbwDveT)
>
> 1. adj. Lleno o cubierto de polvo.

o el más rebuscado `pulverulento`

> [pulverulento, ta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ue8NsOA)
>
> 1. adj. En estado de polvo. Sustancia pulverulenta.

que sería la opción ideal para indicar que este líquido se ha ido secando, desapareciendo y convirtiéndose en polvo con el paso de los años.

"Púlveo" parece ser una construcción con la misma raíz que por ejemplo "pulverizar"

> el lat. *pulvis*, -ĕris 'polvo'.
>
> 1. tr. Reducir a polvo algo. U. t. c. prnl.

"Pulverulento" viene también del latín *pulverulentus*.

El uso de `púlveo` parece ser más una licencia poética que una palabra de nuevo cuño no añadida todavía al diccionario, dada lo escaso de su uso. Entiendo que intenta transmitir "convertido en o compuesto casi exclusivamente de polvo" más que "lleno de polvo".

---

[Otro ejemplo del uso de `púlveo`](https://books.google.com/books?id=hC4sJe14t0EC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=p%C3%BAlveo&source=bl&ots=egSlhWpM-e&sig=5iMqRiknSwge-kpiOCqo7j9dPjU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijupLl_sbZAhURm-AKHWLRBKUQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=p%C3%BAlveo&f=false).

> con ronca voz cansada
>
> del labio balbuciente,
>
> Quisiera la inocente
>
> Los dioses invocar;
>
> Mas ya convulsa, helada,
>
> Huyó el vivir del pecho,
>
> Y en frio **púlveo** lecho
>
> Se mira reposar
>
> <sub>[Fuente: *Composiciones poéticas a la Sra. Concepción Rodríguez: célebre actriz de los ...* by Juan Antonio Suárez](https://books.google.com/books?id=hC4sJe14t0EC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=p%C3%BAlveo&source=bl&ots=egSlhWpM-e&sig=5iMqRiknSwge-kpiOCqo7j9dPjU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijupLl_sbZAhURm-AKHWLRBKUQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=p%C3%BAlveo&f=false)</sub>

Comment: ¡Ah! Mi profesor de Relatividad General llamaba "materia pulverulenta" a lo que en inglés se conoce como ["dust matter" o "cold matter"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137352/could-dust-equation-of-state-have-some-negative-pressure) (materia con presión cero) y veo que [no es el único en hacerlo](https://books.google.es/books?id=5y6okZ6U_S8C&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=%22materia+pulverulenta%22&source=bl&ots=wCzcBg-i4d&sig=ACfU3U2z_TI5mMGuwrnR3cSQ2GryddBAIQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEnd-emKrqAhURmhQKHS3yB-oQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22materia%20pulverulenta%22%20relatividad&f=false).